# Swift Extension Not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, objective-c-category

I've added an extension to UIColor for some colors that I use throughout my app. Here's an example:

```
extension UIColor {
    func appLightGrayColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 190.0/255.0, green: 190.0/255.0, blue: 190.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func grayScaleColor(grayScale : CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: grayScale/255.0, green: grayScale/255.0, blue: grayScale/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

However, when I try to call it, the only way that I've been able to compile without errors is this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.appLightGrayColor(UIColor())()
```

Here's what I get with autocomplete:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Bryan's answer is still correct, with the release of Swift 3, the preferred "Swifty" way of doing things has changed a bit.

With Swift 3, predefined UIColors are used accordingly:

```
var myColor: UIColor = .white // or .clear or whatever
```

Therefore, if you want something similar, such as the following...

```
var myColor: UIColor = .myCustomColor
```

...then, you would define the extension like so:

```
extension UIColor
    {
    public class var myCustomColor: UIColor
        {
        return UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 248/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
```

In fact, Apple defines white as:

```
public class var white: UIColor
```

Comment: Talking about the "Swifty" way of doing things... Shouldn't opening braces be on the same line as the statement? :)

Comment: Don't get me started on that!  It will only become a religious war. :-)

Comment: haha I know I know - everyone has their way :P I follow something similar to https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Answer (score 19):

You have added instance method, but what you really want is [class method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_307)

```
extension UIColor {
    class func appLightGrayColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 190.0/255.0, green: 190.0/255.0, blue: 190.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    class func grayScaleColor(grayScale : CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: grayScale/255.0, green: grayScale/255.0, blue: grayScale/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, also, I suggest that `appLightGrayColor() -> UIColor { return UIColor.grayScaleColor(190.0) }`